# How do I change display scale on Windows from 1920x1440 to 1920x1080?

Tags: windows-10, display

Not sure if this is the right place to ask so apologize if so. I have windows 10 os on a VirtualBox instance and even when changing Maximum guest screen size it gives me options like 1920x1440 instead of the usual 1920x1080. Without boring you with reason I need 1920x1080 for this VirtualBox Windows 10 instance, any insights into how to do this?

Apologies for bad spelling written on phone.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Scale in the Windows 10 Guest, not from Virtual Box. You do this for any guest machine.

Inside a guest machine you should be able to use fractional settings as well. This Kali machine is 1263x804 as a guest inside VMware Workstation.

You may need to put VBox into Windowed Mode (large Window) so the Windows 10 guest settings can be adjusted as you need. With VBox in Windowed Mode you should be able to achieve any guest resolution you need. I do this here.

Screen Shot below is for Windows 10. Use Start, Settings, System, Display.

[image]

Comment: Hey man, my bad 100% I don't think I was clear. I can not access 1920x1080 the only choice it gives me is 1920x1440. I believe this may be due to Mac screen aspect ratio or virtual box but have been unable to fix this

Comment: Put Virtual Box into Windowed Mode (large size Window) and fit it that way.